# how to add python perspective in rcp

Tags: eclipse, pydev, rcp, e4

i am working with eclipse oxygen, i download pydev 6.3.2 and this was added to eclipse.

Now i want add Pydev in my custom rcp application, i read vogella book but i can't figure out how do this.

If anyone have the tip of the iceberg where i can start i will be thankful.

I have a e3 rcp application with Pydev Perspective already working but i want updated the technologies that i am working now that is i why start with e4.

In e3 i add the pydev plugins trougth Windows, Preferences, Plug-in Development, Target Platform.

Then i added in Dependence Tab in plugin.xml the "com.python.pydev.*"

Last step was create an button and in the handler put the next code

```
public class ShowPydevPerspective extends AbstractHandler 
{
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException 
{
    ViewUtility.OpenPerspective("org.python.pydev.ui.PythonPerspective");
    return null;
}
}
```

When the app run and click on the button the pydev perspective appears with all the context.

I try to do the same steps in e4 but is not working.

I added in my plugin.xml , dependece tab all

```
org.python.pyedev.*
org.eclipse.ui.*
```

I added too a button with the code that i mentioned after.

I have the following error, has you see in the image attached.

[pydev integration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMiFR.png)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

PyDev is written for e3 and won't run in a pure e4 app. If you want to use this stick to an e3 RCP.

You can't just include `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` plugins in an e4 app {with one or two exceptions) - these are 3.x compatibility mode code and require a lot of setup that e4 doesn't do.

Comment: Hi, I thought that version 6.3.2 could be used without the compatibility layer. _Release 6.3.2 (2018-03-17)
Important PyDev now requires Java 8 and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) onwards.

PyDev 5.2.0 is the last release supporting Eclipse 4.5 (Mars).
Type inference

Initial support for .pyi stub files (#PyDev-903) -- note that currently .pyi needs to be along the typed .py file.
Improvements to determine if a completion references a bound or unbound method.
Fixed issue opening code completion preferences page._ From[link] http://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html

Comment: Nothing in that text says it can be used without the compatibility layer - it would be a **huge** rewrite to work with just e4 (and probably actually impossible). Language support plugins like PyDev make extensive use of compatibility layer code which is not available in pure e4.

Comment: ah ok, i misunderstand the release note. I thought  that not need the compatibility layer, i will try to make work with compatibility layer. thank you very much.